# Ошибка при подключении к NATS с помощью go

Tags: golang

Я пытаюсь создать издателя для NATS с watermill, NATS сервер запустил как в документации:

```
docker run --name nats --network nats --rm -p 4222:4222 -p 8222:8222 nats --http_port 8222 --cluster_name test-cluster --cluster nats://0.0.0.0:6222
```

Все запустилось, в консоли пишет `[INF] Cluster name is test-cluster`

Код подключения выглядит таким образом:

```
publisher, err := nats.NewStreamingPublisher(
    nats.StreamingPublisherConfig{
        ClusterID:   "test-cluster",
        ClientID:    "test",
        StanOptions: []stan.Option{stan.NatsURL("nats://localhost:4222")},
        Marshaler:   nats.GobMarshaler{},
    }, logger,
)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

и возвращает ошибку: `cannot connect to nats: stan: connect request timeout (possibly wrong cluster ID?)`

В чем может быть проблема?

использую вот эту либу: https://github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/watermill-nats

Comment: а если в option добавить `stan.ConnectWait(time.Second * 15)` ?

Comment: разобрался, в этой либе используется deprecated nats-streaming-server, а я юзал просто nats-server, так что просто написал pub/sub для nats-server вместе с jetstream, который пришел на замену streaming-server